# Live Streaming App iOS

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I am trying to develop a live-streaming application like the meerkat app, where user A can broadcast a live stream while other users are able to watch it. I am having trouble understanding the architecture and mechanisms used to upload video to a server. Currently, I am using a dedicated server with `FFMPEG` installed on it. I also know `FFServer` can be used to perform `RTSP` communication, but I am still unclear how to do this. Can anyone guide me on this?

I would like to know how to upload videos to a server or whether there is another way to perform a live stream. Open source frameworks are welcome.

Comment: if you want any help please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i was in search of something open source which can be implemented without any additional cost. Luckily found Red5 Server (Open Source) https://github.com/Red5/red5-server

I had configured it on my dedicated server and running perfectly fine. Now as server side issue is solved. I need something thing to work on iOS side. For that also i found https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos3x

So with the combination of this two repos i was able to make an live streaming app like meerkut

Thanks

Comment: Did you got it worked?MediaLibDemos3x was having so many issues.Can you help me with the workflow if you don't mind?Something that i can start with .Right from the video capture.

Comment: @abhi1992 I am also facing that problem. Jay if you can help then please give some hint.

Answer (score 1):

for Live streaming video/audio http://www.wowza.com/ give you the best functionality. you have to set up your server in WOWZA  also you cant test in that.

for IOS you can broadcast and receive from the below demo you can download from [here](https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos3x)

i think it's helpful to you :)

Comment: i am aware about wowza but i need to setup the whole thing on my own server and wowza is not free its paid service

Comment: can you guide me how can i configure it in my server ?

Comment: it's long process to configure sever , please follow the forums and other user guild of wowza... you can start from here.. http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?217-How-to-install-and-configure-Wowza-Streaming-Engine